# Python: Error usando request.get

Tags: python, python-requests

Estoy intentando descargar información de [www.mibgas.es](http://www.mibgas.es) y cuando intento conectarme tengo un error de conexión al estar en una red corporativa. Si me desconecto de la red corporativa, funciona sin problema. Cuando me conecto a otras API, aun estando en red, también me funciona.

El codigo es muy simple:

```py
import requests
year=2023
path = f'https://www.mibgas.es/en/file-access/MIBGAS_Data_{year}.xlsx?path=AGNO_{year}/XLS'
response = requests.get(path)
```

Si alguien ha tenido un problema similar y sabe como solucionarlo, agradecería ayuda.

Comment: Quizá la red corporativa tiene proxy. Verifica eso y si lo tiene entonc3s debe incluir los datos del proxy

Comment: He mirado a ver si tenia proxy y parece que no: Cuando ejecuto: netsh winhttp show proxy desde cmd me indica:                                   
 Configuración actual del proxy WinHTTP:

    Acceso directo (sin servidor proxy).

Comment: No se si lo estoy mirando mal, ya que a priori, deberia de tener proxy corporativo. Tambien trate de configurarlo, pero algo debo hacer mal pq no me lo permite

Comment: Conectado a tu red corporativa has un *tracert www.mibgas.es* y fíjate que ruta está tomando y donde se queda. Si se queda en algún ip local de la red corporativa entonces si no es proxy es un firewall. ¿puedes navegar con un browser hacia ese URL estando en la red corporativa? Si puedes navegar con un browaser fíjate si te sale algún mensaje de certificado. Aunque acabo de entrar y no da mensaje de certificado. Chequea con el tracert.

Comment: desde el browser puedo entrar sin problema. incluso la descarga de información, si la hago con powerquery me lo permite. He probado el tracert, y diria que se queda en la primera IP que detecta que empieza por 10.xxx que entiendo es la corporativa. Lo he intentado con otras paginas y ninguna me funciona desde python-Anaconda. Si utilizo el que tiene la compañia en la nube si que me funciona.